# How-to Trigger VPN-On-Demand with MonoTouch

Tags: c#, web-services, xamarin.ios

My Monotouch apps consume and use aspx web services to retrieve and update various server-side things the usual.NET way.  Works great.  However, doing that does not cause the VPN-On-Demand feature in iOS to trigger (auto-connect the first time), even though other apps on the same device like Safari does.

Does anybody know what I have to do (or if it's possible) to get that to happen?  It's supposed to be automatic, but I believe it has something to do with which lower level iOS calls are being made.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Use Runtime.StartWWAN (Uri uri) to force the app to connect/start the VPN

Comment: Thanks for that.  Is there a lot of overhead to call this if the network is already active?  I guess I'm asking what the strategy should be - wait for a failure call StartWWAN and try again, or just call it all the time just in case?  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Providing you have the VPN on-demand setup correctly this should work as long as your HttpClient implementation is using NSUrlSession. You control that through Options >> iOS Build >> HttpClient implementation. This is only available from iOS 7 but I assume that shouldn't be a problem.